Acabe de copiar este repositorio en visual de vue.js y tengo un problema a la hora del run server

    
PS C:\xampp\htdocs\calidad-001\gestor_archivos_php> vue --version 
    vue : No se puede cargar el archivo C:\Users\COMPUTADOR\AppData\Roaming\npm\vue.ps1 porque la ejecución de scripts está deshabilitada en este     
    sistema. Para obtener más información, consulta el tema about_Execution_Policies en 
    
   
    
    https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
    En línea: 1 Carácter: 1
    + vue --version
    + ~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
    PS C:\xampp\htdocs\calidad-001\gestor_archivos_php> npm run serve
    npm ERR! code ENOENT
    npm ERR! syscall open
    npm ERR! path C:\xampp\htdocs\calidad-001\gestor_archivos_php\package.json
    npm ERR! errno -4058
    npm ERR! enoent Could not read package.json: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\xampp\htdocs\calidad-001\gestor_archivos_php\package.json'
    npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
    npm ERR! enoent
    
    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\COMPUTADOR\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-04-19T16_23_43_769Z-debug-0.log       
    PS C:\xampp\htdocs\calidad-001\gestor_archivos_php>``

repositorio
El repositorio de github es:
https://github.com/parzibyte/gestor_archivos_php.git

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! y en que carpeta esta el package.json?
